# Trying to sort through a map by changing the keys and the values accordingly?

Tags: java, collections

Hi I'm trying to Sort through a Map I am sure there are lots of ways but I wanted to make my own way but for some reason my program is not working :(
Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Program {
public static Map<Integer,String> sortMap(Map<Integer,String> m){
    Set<Integer> ll = new HashSet<>(m.keySet());
    Integer[] num = ll.toArray(new Integer[ll.size()]);
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>(ll);
    Collections.sort(l);
    Map<Integer,String> newMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0; i<l.size(); i++){
    for(int j=i+1; j<ll.size(); j++){
        if(l.get(i) == num[j]){
            newMap.put(l.get(i), m.get(num[j]));
            break;
        }
    }
    }
    System.out.println(l);
    return newMap;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Integer,String> hm = new HashMap<>();
    //Random Data Code
    hm.put(666, "Zebra");
    hm.put(555, "Yolo");
    hm.put(444, "Micky you so fine!");
    hm.put(333, "You Blow My Mind");
    hm.put(222, "Apple");
    hm.put(111, "Hey Mickey!");
    Map<Integer,String> m = sortMap(hm);
    // Printing the sorted Map
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> a : m.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(a.getKey() + ":" + a.getValue());
    }
}

}
```

The Console is meant to print the sorted map from small id to big id but it prints

```
333:You Blow My Mind
222:Apple
111:Hey Mickey!
```

I really Appreciate the help.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't sort a HashMap. There is simply no concept of order within a map or set. You can use LinkedHashMap - that one keeps at least track of insertion order.

But the better approach would be to step back and use lists here. You might create a wrapper class that holds that pair of key/value objects that you currently store in your map - and then either implement the Comparable interface or create a Comparator in order to use the sort method provided by java.util.Collections.

Comment: LinkedHashMap Was the way to go for me.